# Virtualenv is installing with wrong version of Python

Tags: python, virtualenv

I recently have started learning python and have run into an issue.

When I run python on my mac without virtualenv, the version number is `Python 2.7.5`. Unfortunately, when I go into my virtualenv, and run Python, the version number is `Python 2.6.1`.

I tried, creating another virtualenv using:

`virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 newdev`

but got: `The executable /usr/bin/python2.7 (from --python=/usr/bin/python2.7) does not exist`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify the executable, not the whole path. For example:

```
mkvirtualenv --python=python3 mynewenv
```

Answer (score 2):

virtualenv --python=python3 mynewenv